# Unit testing with jasmine for login authentication on post credential issue

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am using Angular app and I have service "AuthenticationService" to post user auth data to server via controller. I am beginner of Jasmine unit test. I cannot understand why this issue comes up.

> error: cannot read Property 'andReturn' of 'Undefined;

Maybe because of I have post some data.

My controller code is:

```
  angular.module('webApp')
.controller('LoginController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'AuthenticationService', function ($rootScope, $scope, AuthenticationService ) { 
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.errors = {};
    $scope.authenticationError = false;
    $scope.rememberMe = true;

    $scope.login = function (event) {

        event.preventDefault();
        AuthenticationService.Login({   // service called $http.post to send credentials.
                                    username: $scope.username,
                                    password: $scope.password,
                                    rememberMe: $scope.rememberMe
        },function(response){

            if(response.userName==undefined){
                $scope.authenticationError = true;
            }else{

                AuthenticationService.SetCredentials(response.userName,response.createToken);
            }

        });
    };
}]);
```

My service code is:

```
angular.module('webApp').service('AuthenticationService',function($http,$cookieStore,$rootScope,$q,$location,$timeout){

'use strict';
this.Login =function(credentials, callback){
   console.log(credentials);
    var usernameData=credentials.username;
    var passwordData=credentials.password;
    var data1={"userName":usernameData,"password":passwordData}

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http.post('authenticate', data1).success(function (response) {

    callback(response);
    console.log(deferred.resolve(response));
       }).error(function(error){

        deferred.resolve(error);
        callback(error);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
});
```

and my test code is:

```
describe('testController', function () {
    var $controller, $scope, AuthenticationService;
    var dt = {username: "user1", password: "user1", rememberMe: true};

    beforeEach(module('webApp', function($provide){
        AuthenticationService = jasmine.createSpyObj("AuthenticationService", ["Login"]);

        AuthenticationService.Login.and.returnValue(dt);
    }));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, $rootScope, _AuthenticationService_){
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        AuthenticationService = _AuthenticationService_;
        $controller = _$controller_("LoginController", {
            $scope : $scope,
            AuthenticationService : AuthenticationService
        })
    }));

    it("should load the service", function(){
        expect(AuthenticationService.Login).toHaveBeenCalled();
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AuthenticationService` service isn't mocked, local variable is overridden by real service:

```
AuthenticationService = _AuthenticationService_;
```

It can be mocked with

```
beforeEach(module('webApp', {
  AuthenticationService : { Login: jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(dt) }
}));
```